# Width of column containing Font Awesome characters in tabular

Tags: tables, width, fontawesome

I'm trying to use Font Awesome icons on my `tabular`, but the alignments of the columns break down if all rows include a Font Awesome icon.

When I have this code:

```
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
\textbf{\faLinkedin} & \, \, & something
\textbf{\faXing}  & \, \, & something
\textbf{\faSkype}  & \, \, & something
something & \, \, & different
\end{tabular}
```

I get the output:

[image]

Which is totally fine. However for the following code (only omitting the last row):

```
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
\textbf{\faLinkedin} & \, \, & something
\textbf{\faXing}  & \, \, & something
\textbf{\faSkype}  & \, \, & something
\end{tabular}
```

I get the output :

[image]

Whereas, my desired output is basically this:

[image]

*(I'm using a custom document class based on article, XeLaTeX as compiler, and things are working fine on another parts of the document.)*

Comment: You can specify the "spacing column" using `@{\hspace{1em}}` or `@{\,\,}` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a fixed-width (`p{<len>}`) column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{5em} l}
  \faLinkedin & Linkedin \\
  \faXing     & Xing     \\
  \faSkype    & Skype
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.